# What tools do I need to properly multi box in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I already own multiple account (4), so I need tools **that are authorized by Blizzard** to:

- Be able to control 4 games at once (1 keyboard and 1 mouse)
- Be able to see one screen in large and the other in small (and ideally be able to easily switch)

Note : tools would be programs and maybe in-game addons/macros

Return of experience of successful multi boxers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the WoW multiboxing rules less stringent than EVE Online?  An EVE player set up totally asinine contraptions to comply with CCP's draconian rules.  http://sites.google.com/site/khromtor/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the current top answer from a similar question From: [EpicAdvice.com - What are the best resources for multiboxing?](http://epicadvice.com/questions/1964/what-are-the-best-resources-for-multiboxing/1980#1980)
.

> I used Refer-a-friend and referred myself (it is legal as long as you buy
>   a second copy of WOW).  RAF gave me a
>   large exp bonus so leveling went
>   quickly.
>
> [Dual-Boxing.com](http://dual-boxing.com) has a very good
>   wiki on how to get started.  Since
>   most computers these days have enough
>   CPU and Memory, I ran both toons off
>   of my main computer.  I used a free
>   program [Hot Key Net](http://www.hotkeynet.com/) that allowed
>   me to do picture in picture with both
>   WOW sessions up.  It took some time,
>   but after I got it setup it was very
>   fun.  There is also a section on
>   dual-boxing about the pro's and con's
>   of different class combination to
>   level.

Comment: http://www.wowwiki.com/Multiboxing_software also has a great link to autohotkey setups, to clone keys between the different windows.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already accepted an answer for this question, but hands down, the best software to use is ISBoxer. It will cost you a bit of money ($15 for 3 months I believe), but even as a Keyclone/Autohotkey/HotkeyNet veteran for many years, even the most complex macros that could be written can't come close to what ISBoxer does for you out of the box.

Most notable feature is mouse repeater regions. For example, I have a region with the health bars of my party near the left side of my screen as a result I can tank and DPS with the keyboard while healing with mouse clicks that are passed from the main window (or any window, for that matter) to my healer's window. This was previously nigh impossible or impractical with the other software.

Other features include FTL (Focusless, Leaderless, Targetless setup). Previously you would have to use one of these to keep track of which was the leader character, but ISBoxer virtualizes it all for you and leaves your focus and target spots free.

If you're wondering, my group setups are 5x Paladin (1 prot, 3 ret, 1 holy) and also 4x shamans. I've 2, 3, 4, and 5 boxed for several years already. Each group size and class composition offers different challenges.

As the poster above said, [dual-boxing.com](http://dual-boxing.com) is your best resource for everything related to multiboxing.

Answer (score 0):

To multibox all you really need is a program that will clone your key strokes to multiple instances of wow and to purchase multiple copies.  I used to use [Keyclone](http://solidice.com/keyclone/db/keyclone_current.exe).  If you want to clone your mouse as well you can use [Mouseclone](http://mousecloner.com/), though I don't recommend it.

It practice though, you'll need more than keycloning software, you'll need something which will arrange your windows nicely for you. I hear [pwnboxer](http://pwnboxer.com) is excellent and will clone your keystrokes as a benefit.

Finally you're going to need a series of macro's.  These will usually be:

```
/assist player1 
/cast spell
```

or something similar.

It's usually good to pick the same class multiple times as most of your interactions will be identical.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac (OS X) you can use [CloneKeys](http://code.google.com/p/clonekeys/), a free utility to achieve the replication of keystrokes.

Make macros like the one tzenes described and bind them to the numeric Keypad (for example) or to SHIFT-1,2,3,4,5 on your secondary accounts.

So when you press SHIFT-1, your other “boxes” will execute actions.
I remember having a series of “quick” help me macros (ran a rogue/mage dual box), so I had macros to poly my target, slow, etc. I was a rogue with Polymorph and frostbolts :)

Answer (score 0):

I used Autohotkey and a lot of assist macros.